# How did `DATE` possibly happened to implicit convert `NUMBER` during `nvl(sysdate-my_date_col,sysdate)`

Tags: oracle11g

Let `my_date_col` is `DATE` type, `my_num_col` is `NUMBER` type. Based on the information difference between 2 dates is a number, how is this possible

```
nvl(my_num_col,sysdate)  //syntax error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE"  

nvl(sysdate-my_date_col,sysdate) // works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

Date cannot be converted to numeric type in Oracle. In the matrix for implicit conversion of datatypes given at [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#g195937) you can clearly see that Date and numbers cannot be converted to each other. Also it is mentioned at [nvl docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) that

> The arguments expr1 and expr2 can have any datatype. If their datatypes are different, then Oracle Database implicitly converts one to the other. If they are cannot be converted implicitly, the database returns an error.

That's why you are getting error on converting from number to date in the 1st case and not in converting from one date to another in 2nd case.

Comment: What about in the second case `sysdate-my_date_col` would be a number, Why did `nvl`not return error?